# Object Mesh is not showing the wireframe in solid mode

Tags: wireframe

i was using blender 2,79 and when i upgraded blender to 3.0 i got a problem.

The mesh of my object in solid mode ,when i press z to see the wireframe it shows an outline of the object transparent [image: cheese]  and in that way i can't select anything. i can select the object in solid mode without going to z>wireframe.

the wireframe should appear like this from right to left
[image: Butter]

thank you

Comment: i don´t know how to use the image tool

Comment: you used it, but then you edited its formmating a bunch because you didn’t trust it, and it made it not display properly. Hang on, I’ll fix it.

Comment: please provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: What is your Graphics Card? You have to use graphics card with OpenGL 3.3 support

Comment: @Crantisz i have AMD A4-6210 APU with AMD Radeon R3

Comment: Make sure that you have installed the latest drivers. This problem is quite typical for AMD graphic cards.